# Trigger / Parse Push notification icon

Tags: android, trigger.io

How do you customize the push notification icon on a Trigger.io app?

I am currently testing on Android.

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you would like to alter the app icon badge after it has been changed as a result of a Parse push notification using "badge" data as described here in their docs:
https://parse.com/docs/rest#push

Currently there is no Forge API to do this, but it makes sense for us to add this to the platform. I've raised a ticket for it and will report back here when it is ready.

As a workaround for now, you could trigger another push notification setting the "badge" value to an empty string from within your app - you'd have to create a channel per unique install to do this. Not ideal, but it should work.