# Is it possible to remove push notification Badges with trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I'm setting a badge to 1 when a user receives a push notification on my trigger.io iOS app (using Parse.com) and want to clear the badge one a user opens the app. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Kris, what would you like a screenshot of?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of people have asked about this and I've answered it here:
[Trigger / Parse Push notification icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296571/trigger-parse-push-notification-icon)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs it, this has now been implemented by the team at Trigger.IO

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/notification.html?highlight=badge#setbadgenumber